# How can I use the following code in an onclick event for a button other than a function()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

How can I use the following code in an onclick event for a button other than a function():

```
{
 $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url: 'noload.php?user-first=<?php print($user_name_first); ?>&user-send=<?php print($_GET['user']); ?>',
                success: function(data){
                        $("#search-result").html(data);
                }
             });  
}
```

Comment: trying to accomplish something like: <button onclick="*THAT CODE HERE SO IT CAN EXECUTE W/ OUT A FUNCTION*"></button>

Comment: Advice: use a function.

Comment: @JohnStrickler Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Is there a good reason to avoid using a function or it's just because you're too "wild" for that?

Comment: @Pete Allport functions just want to be your friend.

Comment: @Pete I guess this... `<button onclick="$.ajax({type:'GET',url:'noload.php?user-first=blah&user-send=blah',success:function(data){$('#search-result').html(data);}});">Button</button>`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Please post this as an answer so I can accept this as the answer I used, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the HTML standard, `onclick` and other event handler attributes contain JavaScript code.

See details here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes

Therefore, you can put your JavaScript code directly inside the `onclick` attribute:

```
<button onclick=" /* JavaScript code here */ "> Button </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way

```
<input type="submit" onclick="function() { //your code }">
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put the code there?  What good does that function do, in other words?